# How can I quit Emacs from within a term within Emacs?

Tags: terminal-emacs, ssh, term

I'm in a situation where I have to ssh into a machine and do all of my coding on there. For a while I would ssh in and then use tmux and `emacs -nw` mode. Recently, I discovered the `term` command. Now instead of using tmux, I open up normal Emacs on my desktop and use `term` to ssh in.

Once I'm in, I run `emacs -nw` from within `term` within Emacs on my desktop. This works great, and I have all of my pretty colors. The only problem is, I can't figure out how to cleanly close the `emacs -nw` within the Emacs on my desktop. `C-x C-c` does not work, as expected.

**How can I close the innermost Emacs, and get back to `term`?** Is there a better way to edit files via ssh?

Comment: Ah. I think I've figured it out. This page has helped me a ton: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Exiting.html

Comment: A better way - or at least another way - is to use Tramp to edit files over ssh.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few answers here.

### Quitting Emacs without `C-x C-c`

First, you can quit emacs by running the command that `C-x C-c` is bound to: `M-x save-buffers-kill-terminal`.

### Alternatives to recursive Emacs

Emacs is able to edit files on remote servers, so you don't even need to ssh into the remote server, and you won't need an Emacs inside a term inside your original Emacs. This functionality is called [TRAMP](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/), an acronym for "Transparent Remote (file) Access, Multiple Protocol". To edit a file on a remote server, run `C-x C-f` like normal, but instead of finding the file normally, use a [special format for the file path](https://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#File-name-Syntax): `/user@host:path/to.file`

So if you want to edit the file located at `/etc/hosts` on the remote server `my-remote-machine`, and you need to log in as `gragas`, find the file this way:

```
C-x C-f /gragas@my-remote-machine:/etc/hosts
```

It will prompt you for a password if one is required. It'll transparently save the file across the network, so absent a bit longer time it takes to save, you won't even notice it's a remote file.

Comment: As a complete beginner, I was confused at what `C` meant. Please add to your description that `C` is `ctrl` on an ordinary PC. So it is `ctrl+x`, pause, and `ctrl+c`. The `esc` button can break this sequence, so don't use it while quitting.

Comment: @t7e The first thing any beginner in emacs should do is run the built-in tutorial. Press and hold Contral and then press h, followed by pressing t (for tutorial). On the very first page it explains The C-x C-x style keystroke labels. This is all very commonly used in emacs.

Answer (score 1):

```bash
kill $(ps -o ppid= -p $$)
```

Which is a bit more general: when run from terminal started from Emacs it will look for the parent process of the current process (`$$` is shell's way to get the process id of the current process).  And kill it.  You could put this in your bash profile as a function or alias to make it easier to type, eg:

```
ekill() { kill $(ps -o ppid= -p $$) }
```

In your `~/.bash_profile` (on remote machine), and then you'd only need to type `ekill` once you want to kill Emacs from inside `term` run by Emacs.